# Angular 4 gif loading not working on IE 11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to show animated gif or using css to show loading inductor till app loading, my solution working fine on chrome and Firefox, if ployfills enabled IE hang and indicator will freeze till loading complete,  any suggestions or solution for this problem?

new app created using angular cli
 1. ng new appname
 2. the following css added to style.css

```js
 pollyfills.ts un-commented 
 

    /** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-j
```

```css
   .splash-logo {
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        margin-left: -26px;
        margin-top: -30px;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
        width: 54px;
    }

    .splash-loader,
    .splash-loader::before,
    .splash-loader::after {
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      margin-left: -45px;
      margin-top: -45px;
      position: absolute;
      vertical-align: middle;
      background: #006fff ;
      width: 90px;
      height: 90px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .splash-loader::before {
      content: "";
      animation: bounce 1.5s infinite;
    }
    .splash-loader::after {
      content: "";
      animation: bounce 1.5s -0.4s infinite;
    }

    @keyframes bounce {
      0% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(2);
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes bounce {
      0% {
        transform: scale(0.8);
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        transform: scale(2);
        -webkit-transform: scale(2);
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }

    .splash-screen {
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
     index.html
     <app-root>
         <div class="splash-screen">
             <div class="splash-loader"></div>
          </div>
      </app-root>
```

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: I guess it could be related to missing `web-animations-js` polyfill it it is not would you mind to show the exact error ?